# How to access EAAccessories?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, external-accessory

```
eaManager = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
[eaManager registerForLocalNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotDevice)  name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
```

`[eaManager connectedDevices]` is always empty.

How can I pair to a accessory?

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your iPhone to a Made for iPod program device which provides a protocol for being accessed by the External Accessory framework.  There aren't many of those out there right now.  I believe that TomTom's [iPhone Car Kit](http://iphone.tomtom.com/en-us/car-kit-for-iphone.html) is one of them, but I can't think of others.